# Any workarounds for handling issues with `nvarchar(MAX)` in Erlang ODBC?

Tags: erlang, odbc, elixir

There seem to be some issues in Erlang ODBC relating to `nvarchar(MAX)` and `varchar(MAX)`.

For example running  `SELECT 'Bob' [name], 50 [age] FOR JSON PATH` should give the following:

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
-----------------------------------------
[{"name":"Bob","age":50}]
```

Erlang ODBC produces:

```
{:selected, ['JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B'],
 [
   [
     <<0, 0, 80, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 75, 246, 34, 87, 97, 33, 0, 128, 32, 0, 70, 0, 105, 0, 108, 0, 74, 246, 33, 87, 92, 34, 0, 128, 105, 0, 99, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 73, 246, 32, 87, 102, 35, 0, 128, 32,
       0>>
   ]
 ]}
```

and on another run ...

```
{:selected, ['JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B'],
 [[<<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 207, 63, 70, 190, 0, 5, 0, 142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 204, 63, 69, 190, 253, 6, 0, 138, 7, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 205, 63, 68, 190, 0, 7, 0, 137, 112, 97>>]]}
```

I'm using the following connection settings:

```
timeout: 30_000,
auto_commit: :on,
binary_strings: :on,
tuple_row: :off,
scrollable_cursors: :off,
trace_driver: :off,
extended_errors: :on
```

The output of the [`FOR JSON` clause is of type `nvarchar(MAX)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-variables).

Please are there any workarounds for handling issues with `nvarchar(MAX)` in Erlang ODBC.

Comment: What do you get if you configure `binary_strings` to `:off`?

Comment: @SteveVinoski same random binary results

Comment: I cannot find anything definitive one way or the other but I would be pretty surprised if the ODBC driver supported the "for json" clause.  ODBC doesn't really support much beyond ANSI standard SQL--intentionally.

Comment: If I were you, I'd first be asking if the SQL-Server ODBC driver supports the "FOR JSON" clause at all.  You probably want to post a question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ because you're more likely to get a knowledgeable answer there.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci thanks for this answer, but my test show that the problem is deeper than that. Even `SELECT cast('Hi Joe' as nvarchar(MAX)) [msg]` fails, with `nvarchar(MAX)` or even `varchar(MAX)`

This leads me to suspect that `Erlang ODBC` driver is unable to handle `nvarchar(MAX)` and `varchar(MAX)` properly.

Comment: This may have some bearing on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517250/how-to-convert-an-elixir-binary-to-a-string  You're using NVARCHAR (unicode vs. ascii encoding) and that may be part of the issue you're seeing.

Comment: the biggest problem i see here is the fact that a simple query like: `SELECT cast('hello' as nvarchar(MAX)) [msg]` gives a different result for each invocation. that seems to point to an issue with ERLANG ODBC handling  nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: I think you're right but I don't think it's the Erlang ODBC driver.  I think it's the ODBC driver in general.  Take a look at this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b59ae1ba-1add-4a93-845e-e4505603d23f/selecting-varcharmax-or-nvarcharmax-columns-using-quotodbc-driver-11-for-sql-serverquot?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci i had seen those links. The complaint there was for `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` i'm running the latest, `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't be terribly surprised if the error is still present.  One person reported the error on ODBC Driver 13.  Someone else reported still seeing the issue on February 28, 2019--so I wouldn't be surprised if the issue is still present.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci your intuition was very correct. There is an elegant solution for this, simply use the OLEDB provider via ODBC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is solution that works fine on windows: use the OLEDB provider via ODBC like below

```
 conn = "Provider=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=#{server};PORT=#{port};DATABASE=#{db};UID=#{uid};PWD=#{pwd};"

    :odbc.connect(
      to_charlist(conn),
      timeout: 30_000,
      # auto_commit: true,
      binary_strings: :on,
      tuple_row: :off,
      # scrollable_cursors: :off,
      # trace_driver: :off,
      extended_errors: :on
    )
```