# erlang:odbc - cannot get correct query results in unicode from mssql

Tags: sql-server, unicode, odbc, elixir, freetds

What i'am trying:
 - just make a select with erlang-odbc from elixir and dump all result to console.

Enviroment:
my side

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
- unixODBC-devel ( yum)
- Elixir 1.8.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)
- Erlang/OTP 21
- erlang-odbc R16B (yum)
- (either) mssql driver
- (or) FreeTds driver 1.1.6 (compiled from sources --with-unixodbc)

target

- mssql server 2016
- table

```
    CREATE TABLE db_name.dbo.rating (
        [Year] int NULL,
        Code varchar(256) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
        Name nvarchar(4000) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
        GroupeCode varchar(256) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
        GroupeName nvarchar(4000) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
        Cost numeric(38,5) NOT NULL,
        PrchasesCount int NULL
        ) GO
```

*nvarchar*: 
    character_set_name: UNICODE 
    collation_name: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

*varchar*:
    character_set_name: **cp1251** 
    collation_name: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

elixir code looks like:

```
conn_str = 
    "SERVER=XX.XX.XX.XX,1433;" <>
     #tried this too! "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" <>
    "DRIVER=FreeTDS;" <>
    "DATABASE=db_name;UID=bot;PWD=XXXXXX;" 
|> to_charlist

 statement = "select top(3) Name from Rating order by Cost desc" |> to_charlist

 {:ok, pid}=:odbc.connect(conn_str,[])

 {:selected, col_names, rows} = :odbc.sql_query(pid, statement)
```

and, after all attempts, i have something like this in result

```
{:selected, ['Name'],
 [
   {<<32, 4, 48, 4, 49, 4, 62, 4, 66, 4, 75, 4, 32, 0, 65, 4, 66, 4, 64, 4, 62,
      4, 56, 4, 66, 4, 53, 4, 59, 4, 76, 4, 61, 4, 75, 4, 53, 4, 32, 0, 63, 4,
      62, 4, 32, ...>>},
   {<<16, 4, 64, 4, 53, 4, 61, 4, 52, 4, 48, 4, 32, 0, 63, 4, 48, 4, 65, 4, 65,
      4, 48, 4, 54, 4, 56, 4, 64, 4, 65, 4, 58, 4, 62, 4, 51, 4, 62, 4, 32, 0,
      66, 4, ...>>},
   {<<35, 4, 65, 4, 59, 4, 67, 4, 51, 4, 56, 4, 32, 0, 63, 4, 62, 4, 32, 0, 64,
      4, 53, 4, 58, 4, 67, 4, 59, 4, 76, 4, 66, 4, 56, 4, 50, 4, 48, 4, 70, 4,
      56, ...>>}
 ]}
```

instead a correct Cyrillic text

its a not random numbers! result always the same.

MS driver gives same result as FreeTDS

what else i've tried

- changing conn options  binary_strings: :on/off
- setting option client charset = UTF-8 in freetds.conf (in global section)
- scratching my head
- using :unicode functions to read << data >>
- using is_binary() on received numbers returns true

Questions

- what type of data do i receive?
- why data is not correct decoded?
- what app is responsible for it?
- how can i fix it?
  some part of freetds log here (about iconv)

```
iconv.c:326:tds_iconv_open(0x1e02330, UTF-8)
iconv.c:186:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:186:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:186:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:186:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:348:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:350:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:389:tds_iconv_open: done
iconv.c:785:setting server single-byte charset to "CP1251"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF-8 and not UTF-16?  See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517250/how-to-convert-an-elixir-binary-to-a-string) for something that may have some bearing on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2019, you're going to want to use a collation that ends in `_UTF8` rather than `_AS`. There's a full article here with details on collation types:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017#utf-8-support

Previous to MSSQL 2019,

I know this works for Python 3.

Comment: i wonder this is about ms sql server configuration, but, alas, it is out of my control. Anyway, they are on 2016 version